# Android disable button if records are added

Tags: android, android-button

I'm doing an android app where user can add records. If the app successfully added the records to the database, it should disable the add button. Otherwise, make it still enabled.

I've done this:

```
     btAdd.setEnabled(false);
```

Do you have any ideas to achieve this? Help is much appreciated.

Comment: share the entire code snippet.. because  btAdd.setEnabled(false); should do the job.. if you share entire code it would be easy for others to find the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try : `button.setClickable(false);`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

> But I can't seem to get the logic for checking if the records are
>   added successfully.

```
long a=database.insert(Table_name, null,values);
if(a!=0)
{
Toast.makeText(context, "Record added successfully",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
button.setClickable(false);
}
```

Not sure if this is what you want exactly. Tell me if I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 0):

As you are [inserting the data to the sqlLite database](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues%29), on successful it `returns rowID` if any error occur the it `returns -1`. So you need to check the return on insertOperation.

```
long rowId =database.insert(Table_name, null,values);
if(rowId != -1)
{
Toast.makeText(context, "Record added successfully",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
button.setClickable(false);
// you can also make it invisible or gone by setting the View for this button if required.
}
```